# Firebase Storage throws insufficient permission error but files is created

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm getting a strange behaviour when trying to upload a file to firebase Storage.

Here is my rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /journals/{userId}/{anyUserFile=**} { //I also tried {allPaths=**}
        allow create, read: if 
        request.auth != null && 
        request.auth.uid == userId &&
        request.resource.size < 1024 && //in bytes, permitted 1kb per note.
        request.resource.contentType == "application/json";
      allow update, delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my method based on the docs.

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://myapp.appspot.com/journals/" + auth.CurrentUser.UserId);
    
StorageReference note = storageRef.Child("/" + filename);

var newMetadata = new MetadataChange
{
    ContentType = "application/json"
};

note.PutFileAsync(path, newMetadata)
.ContinueWithOnMainThread((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
    else {
        // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
        string md5Hash = metadata.Md5Hash;
        Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
        Debug.Log("md5 hash = " + md5Hash);
    }
});
```

I get the following error despite the fact that my object is created, including the user directory if it didn't exist when creating the first object.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (User does not
> have permission to access this object.) --->
> Firebase.Storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to
> access this object.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.Storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.<---